# Mapping returned data from an API to a nested FormArray in Angular

Tags: angular

I am on the final stretch of getting my Invoice to work.  I can successfully add an invoice, but I am battling to write my Angular code to edit an invoice.  In essence, I get the following data returned from my API:

```
{
    "dateRaised": "2022-03-08T19:14:37",
    "paymentDueDate": "2022-03-08T19:14:37",
    "familyGroupId": 1,
    "subTotal": 4500,
    "discountFactor": 1,
    "discountAmount": 10,
    "discountDescription": "Early Settlement",
    "grandTotal": 4050,
    "customerInvoiceLines": [
        {
            "schoolFeeId": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "amount": 4000
        },
{
            "schoolFeeId": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "amount": 500
        }
    ]
}
```

My Angular code is as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
    this.initializeForm();
    this.getFamilyGroups();
    this.getSchoolFees();
    this.getCustomerInvoice(this.id);

    this.editCustomerInvoiceChanges$ = this.editCustomerInvoiceForm.controls["customerInvoiceLines"].valueChanges;
    this.editCustomerInvoiceChanges$.subscribe(invoiceLineItems =>
      this.updateLineItemUnitPrice(invoiceLineItems)
      );
    
    const control = <FormArray>this.editCustomerInvoiceForm.controls["customerInvoiceLines"];
  }

initializeForm() {
    const numberPattern = "^[0-9.,]+R";
    
    this.editCustomerInvoiceForm = this.fb.group ({
      dateRaised: ['', Validators.required],
      paymentDueDate: ['', Validators.required],
      familyGroupId: [0, Validators.required],
      subTotal: [],
      discountFactor: [],
      discountAmount: [],
      discountDescription: [],
      totalDiscount: [{ value: "", disabled: true }],
      grandTotal: [],
      customerInvoiceLines: this.fb.array([
        this.getNewInvoiceLineItem()
      ])
    });
  }
```

I then try mapping the API return data to my form:

```
getCustomerInvoice(id){
    this.customerInvoiceService.getCustomerInvoice(id).subscribe((invoice : any)=> {
      this.editCustomerInvoiceForm.patchValue(invoice);
    });
  }
```

The patchValue only patches the first array item of customerInvoiceLines.  How do I map all invoice lines that are returned in my API?

Answer (score 0):

PathValue **not** add elements to the array. You should add so many FormGroups to your FormArray as data you have.

So, one aproach can be

```
this.customerInvoiceService.getCustomerInvoice(id).subscribe((invoice : any)=> {
      const formArray=this.editCustomerInvoiceForm.get('customerInvoiceLines') as FormArray
      
      formArray.clear();
      invoice.customerInvoiceLines.forEach(_=>{
        formArray.push(this.getNewInvoiceLineItem())
      })
      this.editCustomerInvoiceForm.patchValue(invoice);
    });
```

Personally I prefer to have functions that received an object or null and create the formGroup with the data.

Imagine your function `getNewInvoiceLineItem` becomes like

```
getNewInvoiceLineItem(data:any=null)
{
    data=data || {schoolFeeId: 0,quantity: 0,amount: 0}
    return this.fb.group({
         schoolFeeId:data.schoolFeeId,
         quantity:data.quantity,
         amount:data.amount
    })
}
```

So you could use this function and use some like

```
      const formArray=this.editCustomerInvoiceForm.get('customerInvoiceLines') as FormArray
      formArray=this.fb.formArray(invoice.customerInvoiceLines
          .map(x=>this.getNewInvoiceLineItem(x)))
```

See how you convert each value of the array invoice.customerInvoiceLines in a formGroup, and your formArray is a formArray of this array of FormGroups

Well, Really we can to have another function to create the whole form

```
  getForm(data: any = null) {
    data = data || {
      dateRaised: null,
      paymentDueDate: null,
      familyGroupId: 0,
      subTotal: 0,
      discountFactor: 0,
      discountAmount: 0,
      discountDescription: null,
      totalDiscount: 0,
      grandTotal: 0,
      customerInvoiceLines: null,
    };
    return this.fb.group({
      dateRaised: [data.dateRaised, Validators.required],
      paymentDueDate: [data.paymentDueDate, Validators.required],
      familyGroupId: [data.familyGroupId, Validators.required],
      subTotal: data.subTotal,
      discountFactor: data.discountFactor,
      discountAmount: data.discountAmount,
      discountDescription: data.discountDescription,
      totalDiscount: [{ value: data.totalDiscount, disabled: true }],
      grandTotal: data.grandTotal,
      customerInvoiceLines: data.customerInvoiceLines
        ? this.fb.array(
            data.customerInvoiceLines.map((x) => this.getNewInvoiceLineItem(x))
          )
        : this.getNewInvoiceLineItem(),
    });
  }
```

See then that you can use

```
this.customerInvoiceService.getCustomerInvoice(id).subscribe((invoice : any)=> {
  this.editCustomerInvoiceForm=this.getForm(invoice);
});
```